# How to Get in Rest API using VBS

Tags: vbscript, rest

Long time lurker.. first time poster..

I'm fairly proficient with PowerShell. However, I have a requirement to use a get response to a rest API using VBS and I'm completely out of my depths.

Normally using the following in PowerShell would return me a string for a just in time password.

```
Invoke-RestMethod "https://domain/password" -UseDefaultCredentials
```

I'm attempting to do the same method in VBS but I believe my issue is to do with passing through the credentials. Everything I've tried has failed me and I can't find any relatable KBs

How can I do a API call in VBS?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using curl with a --ntlm switch

```
curl.exe --ntlm -u : -sX GET ""https://domain/password""
```

Comment: That's not VBScript.